# Is this acceptable? - "After selecting an element, a pop-up allows the user to ... "

Tags: sentence-construction, compounds

I wrote this sentence:

> After selecting an element, a pop-up allows the user to create an anchor using the element's text, a text pattern, or specific attributes of the element such as *id*, *class*.

However I most see something like

> After selecting ...., the user creates ....

Does my sentence above is correct too?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the limited context the sentence you wrote is perfectly correct.

If you wanted to follow the template you show you could put it another way:

> After selecting an element, the user creates an anchor, via a pop-up, using the element's...

But I think your original sentence is better.